# Unrecognized statement type. (near "BY" at position 38)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a user using mysql. Please see below query.

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1234*';
```

But, when I execute the query getting below error.

```
Unrecognized statement type. (near "BY" at position 38)
```

Comment: Possible due to accent over I in `ÌDENTIFIED`.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: NO, I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you have the permission rights to create new USER in DB?

Comment: Yes I have. I hope error error message shows some syntax error